# How to test vuex state and mutations correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

tell me how to test mutations and state correctly. I have a modal window component, it is rendered if the showModal property in the state is true. And there is an event that causes a mutation that changes the property.
How to check that after the event is called, the component is no longer rendered? Do I need to import the actual vuex storage?

```
<template>
  <div>
   <transition name="fade" appear>
     <div ref="modal" class="modal-overlay"
       v-if="isShow"
       @click="close">
     </div>
   </transition>
 <transition name="pop" appear>
  <div class="modal"
       role="dialog"
       v-if="isShow"
  >
  <div class="layer">
      <slot name="content"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
</div>
```

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: "VModal",
  computed:{
    ...mapState({
      isShow: state => state.showModal
    })
  },
  methods:{
    close(){
      this.$store.commit('SHOW_OR_HIDE_MODAL', false)
    }
  }
}




import Vuex from "vuex"
import { mount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils"
import VModal from '../../assets/src/components/VModal'
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('testing modal', () => {
let mutations
let state
let store

beforeEach(() => {
    state = {
        showModal: true
    }
    mutations = {
        SHOW_OR_HIDE_MODAL: jest.fn()
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({ state, mutations })
})
test('check close modal', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(VModal, {
        store, localVue
    })

    await wrapper.find(".modal-overlay").trigger("click")

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.find(".modal-overlay").exists()).toBe(false)
    expect(wrapper.find(".modal").exists()).toBe(false)
 })
})
```

And I have index.js with store

[image]

But in test after click I get error
[image]

I understand what I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out how to properly test vuex, sorry for the stupid question, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You mocked SHOW_OR_HIDE_MODAL, so it won't change showModal. Consider testing with real store and reset the state in beforeEach

Comment: Do you mean import index.js with real store and use it in new Vuex.Store() ?

Comment: Yes. You can add reset functionality to the store, or reimport it in beforeEach with jest.isolateModules

Comment: ok I import `import realStore from '../../assets/src/admin/pages/institutes/store/index'` and use in `beforeEach(() => {
        store = new Vuex.Store({ realStore })
    })`

Then I have error with trigger click `await wrapper.find(".modal-overlay").trigger("click")`.  `[vue-test-utils]: find did not return .modal-overlay, cannot call trigger() on empty Wrapper`

Comment: If you expect a modal to be displayed with showModal , you need to make it true

Comment: I import state and mutations from real store and all works fine. After trigger click `".modal-overlay"` to be false. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to reset the state, or you'll run into troubles in next tests

Answer (score 0):

On your test, you are setting your state showModal to true:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  state = {
    showModal: true
  }
  ...
})
```

So your overlay is rendered and that is why your test conditions resolves as true.

```
<div ref="modal" class="modal-overlay"
   v-if="isShow"
   @click="close">
 </div>
enter code here
```

Your 'isShow' computed value is point to the showModal = true on your test.

Comment: but the click trigger should cause a mutation that should change modalShow to false, why after that, for example `expect(wrapper.find(".modal-overlay").exists()).toBe(false)` not working?

Comment: trigger will not 'work' since you are mocking the mutation. Your showModal state will always be true in your test scope. 
In you real app, its fine.